# Ошибка - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, discord

Возникла проблема при написании бота для discord.

```
@client.command(aliases = ['balance', 'cash'])
async def __balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))
           else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""баланс пользователя **{member}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))
```

выдаёт ошибку `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

если в коде убрать индексы то работает, но там где должна быть сумма естественно пишет None:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: попробуйте место `member is None` заменить `member is not None`

Comment: скорее всего один из запросов не находит в базе ничего и возвращает None. попытка получить элемент в None `None[0]` у вас это `fethcone()[0]` возвращает исключение.